# Apache 2.2 "The requested operation has failed."

Tags: php, apache, installation

After installing php on apache with this code:

```
#BEGIN PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP/"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/PHP/php5apache2_4.dll"
#END PHP INSTALLER EDITS - REMOVE ONLY ON UNINSTALL
```

I can't start apache anymore, getting this error message  "The requested operation has failed."

Comment: Are you sure that the file `C:/PHP/php5apache2_4.dll` exists.

Comment: yes ofc php5apache2_4.dll this file is in my php directory